# What's a unique/special case that requires tuple variants in an enum?

Tags: rust

from [Rust tutorial](https://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/tutorial.html#syntax-basics), types can be defined with struct

```rust
enum Shape {
    Circle { center: Point, radius: f64 },
    Rectangle { top_left: Point, bottom_right: Point }
}
```

and non-struct/Tuples type enums (thanks @ÖmerErden for correct nomenclature)

```rust
enum Shape {
    Circle(Point, f64),
    Rectangle(Point, Point)
}
```

As far as I can tell both are identical, have the exact same use cases in match, etc. But the struct one forces you to use named properties and the non-struct forces you to use ordered params.

Is there any other difference I am missing, in usage or output (performance, memory footprint, etc)? Or is the later just a lazy-syntax version of the struct one with the exact outcome after compilation?

Comment: This is tuple => `let x = (3, 5, 4)`, this is tuple struct  => `struct Circle(Point, f64)` and there is no class in Rust

Comment: The "Rust tutorial" you're linking to is from Rust 0.9... Many things changed (both in the syntax and in the standard library) between 0.9 and 1.0, so you'll find some obsolete stuff in this. I recommend you read the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) instead, if you haven't already.

Comment: There should be no observable difference at run time between the two forms. But that's not specific to enums, the same applies to tuple-structs vs ordinary structs in general.

Answer (score 0):

I only found two obvious usages:

- to wrap a type with minimum boilerplate, so every time you need to go down to the wrapped object, it's just `self.0`.

```rust
struct MyString(String);
```

- when `.0`, `.1`, etc syntax adds more clarity and you can't do it with named fields (since an identifier cannot start from a numeric character, in particular cannot be a numeric string

Comment: Can you use `self.0` to access fields of an enum variant?

Comment: That's a special case for Tuple Struct with one value, not really a Special case for an Enum of tuples. Manual says "There is a special case for tuple structs with a single field, which are sometimes called `newtypes`"